# Invalid directory or path error

Tags: php, connection

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721702/windows-7-64-bit-odbc-drivers-for-ms-access-missing Please I used the instruction in the link the fix my problems but now i get the error message when i enter DSN and click ok: invalid directory or path. Please I ll appreciate any for of assistance

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if you've enabled odbc on your php using `phpinfo()`.

This will guide you
http://codexperience.co.za/post/part-1.-connecting-to-a-microsoft-access-database-using-php

Answer (score 0):

check may be your access dB file open close it and then try to create DNS